# Unterminated string Literal, Using PHP in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm getting this error in Firebug :

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Panel_Measurements[i] = "`<br />`

And now all off my functions fail to work...
I've tried multiple solutions, but none of them work...
this is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript>
   <?php
      $i = 0;
      while(isset($dbPanel_Name[$i]))
      {
   ?>

          Panel_brand_type[i]   = "<?php echo addslashes($dbPanel_Brand_Type[$i]); ?>";
          Panel_description[i]  = "<?php echo addslashes($dbPanel_Description[$i]); ?>";
          Panel_measurements[i] = "<?php echo addslashes($dbPanel_Measurements[$i]); ?>";
          Panel_warranty[i] = "<?php echo addslashes($dbPanel_Warranty[$i]); ?>";
          i++;
   <?php
         $i++;
       }
    ?>
</script>
```

If there's any other way to get PHP variables into Javascript, I would love to know!
Any type of help is usefull to me.

Sincerly,

Harmen Brinkman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A much better way of injecting string literals (and pretty much every other type of value too) in JavaScript is [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
Panel_brand_type[i] = <?php echo json_encode($dbPanel_Brand_Type[$i]); ?>;
```

Note that I removed the double quotes around the PHP tags, `json_encode` provides them itself.

The only potential issue with this solution is that the string you are injecting has to be UTF-8, but your existing code with `addslashes` also had a similar problem (it blindly assumes that you are using a single-byte encoding) so IMHO there's no regression.

Finally, *make sure that the PHP variables are actually set* before trying to access them! If there is no such variable, PHP will spew out its warnings where JavaScript code is expected: a sure way to ruin your day.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but when I don't add double quotes Fire bug gives an syntax error of missing quotes, and when I do add them it gives a Syntax error like this : Panel_brand_type[i] = "" value ""; Any suggestions?

Comment: @HarmenBrinkman: If the variables exist in PHP there is nothing else that could cause a JS error (even if the string is not UTF-8, that will result in a `null` value instead of an error). So the only logical explanation is that you are injecting the values of variables that don't exist.

Comment: For some reason it does work now, without extra saving or other changes, I will markt this one as the answer! thank you very much!